# ORA-28110: policy function or package SCOTT.SEC_FUCTION has error

Tags: sql, oracle

as scott, write a policy function to implement the following policy: Users can access id and score without any restriction, but they can only access their own name (using the masking behavior). sysdba should be able to access any data without restrictions.

Table name： RATING

```
        ID NAME                                          SCORE
---------- ---------------------------------------- ----------
         1 SYS                                               4
         2 RHWTT                                             5
         3 LEO                                               4
         4 MOD3_ADMIN                                        5
         5 VPD674                                            4
         6 SCOTT                                             5
         7 HR                                                4
         8 OE                                                5
         9 PM                                                4
        10 IX                                                5
        11 SH                                                4
        12 BI                                                5
        13 IXSNEAKY                                          4
        14 DVF                                               5
```

command:

```
SCOTT > CREATE FUNCTION SEC_FUNCTION ( p_schema IN VARCHAR2, p_object IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
RETURN 'NAME = SYS_CONTEXT (''USERENV'',''SESSION_USER'')';
END;
/  

Function created.

SCOTT > EXECUTE DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY (
          OBJECT_SCHEMA         => 'SCOTT', 
          OBJECT_NAME           => 'RATING', 
          POLICY_NAME           => 'SEC_POLICY', 
          FUNCTION_SCHEMA       => 'SCOTT', 
          POLICY_FUNCTION       => 'SEC_FUCTION', 
          SEC_RELEVANT_COLS     => 'NAME',
          SEC_RELEVANT_COLS_OPT =>  DBMS_RLS.ALL_ROWS);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

ERROR:

```
select * from rating;
ORA-28110: policy function or package SCOTT.SEC_FUCTION has error
```

Comment: did you run "show errors" to see the errors?

Comment: I dont get it. it says "no errors''.

Comment: You've created function `SEC_FUNCTION` but the policy and error refer to `SEC_FUCTION`, without an N. So this looks like a simple typo.

Comment: Yes, can confirm. Works with `SEC_FUNCTION`.  Need to undo my editing, though, as EXECUTE doesn't seem to like line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you remove the typo 'SEC_FUCTION':

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY (
          OBJECT_SCHEMA         => 'SCOTT', 
          OBJECT_NAME           => 'RATING', 
          POLICY_NAME           => 'SEC_POLICY', 
          FUNCTION_SCHEMA       => 'SCOTT', 
          POLICY_FUNCTION       => 'SEC_FUNCTION', 
          SEC_RELEVANT_COLS     => 'NAME',
          SEC_RELEVANT_COLS_OPT =>  DBMS_RLS.ALL_ROWS);
END;
/
```

Then you get the desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM rating;

ID  NAME               SCORE
```

---

```
 1  null                   4
 2  null                   5
 3  null                   4
 4  null                   5
 5  null                   4
 6  SCOTT                  5
 7  null                   4
 8  null                   5
 9  null                   4
10  null                   5
11  null                   4
12  null                   5
13  null                   4
14  null                   5
```